# Acronyms in astrophysics: is there a place that collects them all anywhere on the internet? And what does PSN mean on the TNS server?

Tags: supernova, pulsar

Acronyms in astrophysics: is there a place that collects them all anywhere on the internet?  And what does PSN mean on the TNS server?

Is it "possible supernova" or "pulsar" something?

I have so MANY acronym questions and I never seem to get them all answered, it's frustrating.

Any help is appreciated but mostly I want to be taught how to fish, not just handed a fish, so if there's a great place or places people know about on the internet with lists of commonly used acronyms that are trying at least to be comprehensive, or helpful beyond their own needs, or really anything. I'll take a site simply explaining its own acronyms. Also, I just tried to use the tags "transient" "acronym" and "TNS" all of which were rejected and I don't have the reputation points to create them but I think they would be useful tags on this server. Someone with more points should create them. I have no idea how I get points. I only post when I need something. Should I start answering questions, not just asking them, like 10 minutes a day, or trying to do so? Is that how you get reputation points on Astro SE? I am no "expert" but I could try answering things. Especially basic stuff like what does TNS stand for or AT or for example why is the sky blue, why is a sunset red, and what is the most basic description of airmass and how does it affect me while observing? Stuff like that. But mostly I'm here for your folks' help! Thank you!

Comment: What is "the TNS server"? Is it a website? Can you add a link?

Comment: someone got this answered already but yes. TNS is a wonderful place where you should spend all of your free time!   https://www.wis-tns.org/object/2022jli   just append the end part after the word object with the transient of your choice!  For example here is the very famous 2018cow (not just for the cool combination of letters) https://www.wis-tns.org/object/2018cow. 2018 has its own Wikipedia page!

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the advice, but I already spend "all of my time" in Stack Exchange :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, as I do not know of such a collection of acronyms (besides the humorous [DOOFASS](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Egpetitpas/Links/Astroacro.html)).

But in this case, I just looked up one of the sources on [SIMBAD](https://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=PSN%20J20150317-1959462) (you will also often find the link to SIMBAD on the [Transient Name Server](https://www.wis-tns.org/) or "TNS") and there you can click the blue "PSN" tag under "Identifiers" and will find that it stands for "possible supernova".

Comment: Thank you so much. I got so much out of this answer. Love the DOOFAS list